# Sharepoint 2007 - How to delete a draft page

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I've created a page in Sharepoint for test/demonstration purposes. I checked it in so other developers could review it. Now that it's no longer needed I wish to delete the draft. When I select the page in the Version History, I only see an option for View or Restore, but no Delete. How can I delete this page so the latest version is the last published version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a version - you restore a version that becomes the new version. Then you approve and everything is fine.